# Rendering CCSprite texture gives the old images

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a scene with UIImagePicker. Selecting the image from library will present a new scene with selected image. After presenting a new scene I use the following method to display image which gets called from onEnter method with the picked image from library.

```
-(void) loadPuzzleImage:(UIImage*)selectedImageFromLibrary {

    puzzleImage = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithCGImage:[selectedImageFromLibrary CGImage] key:@"selectedimage"];
    puzzleImage.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
    puzzleImage.opacity = 80.0f;
    puzzleImage.position = ccp(screenSize.width - puzzleImage.contentSize.width - 136,
                                   screenSize.height - puzzleImage.contentSize.height - 48);

    [self addChild: puzzleImage z:1 tag:10];
    [puzzleImage release];
}
```

When I going back and select the new image from library it only shows the previous image. I solved it by using different key for CGIImage in CCSprite allocation. But when I use the Render Texture to get the CCSprite image it returns only the previous image instead of current image. I don't know why.  I used the following code for rendering image.

```
-(UIImage *) convertSpriteToImage:(CCSprite *)sprite {

    CGPoint p = sprite.anchorPoint;
    [sprite setAnchorPoint:ccp(0,0)];
    CCRenderTexture *renderer = [[CCRenderTexture alloc] initWithWidth:sprite.contentSize.width 
                                                                height:sprite.contentSize.height 
                                                           pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
    [renderer begin];
    [sprite visit];
    [renderer end];
    [sprite setAnchorPoint:p];
    return [renderer getUIImage];
}
```

and call this method by

```
UIImage* tempPuzzle = [self convertSpriteToImage:
                           [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:[puzzleImage texture]]];
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you are being fooled by the textureCache. You probably want to change the key for every selectedImage. Otherwise, next time you use a CCSprite ctor, the ctor will first look in the cache for the key and return that texture.

Comment: Yeah. The old image is saved in textureCache. I removed the cached image by using removeTextureForKey method. Thanks @YvesLeBorg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the sprite using a "discardable" texture you should instantly send the `removeTextureForKey:` message with the image name to CCTextureCache. This should be enough to reload the texture with the same key the next time you create a sprite with the same image name.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. I solved the problem by using removeTextureForKey method.